# Replace null field with 0, using condition name in query

Tags: mysql

This is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT ROUND( AVG(p.votes), 2) AS 'votes', games.*
FROM games
LEFT JOIN polls p ON (p.gid = games.id)
GROUP BY games.id;
```

It is working fine, but if there aren't any votes on game in the `polls` table - the `votes` field is NULL then in the result - how can I replace it so it will show `0` instead (as there are `0` rows found in the `polls`).

Also:

Is it possible to name my condition and then use it fe. for calculations in MySQL?

This is what I mean:

```
SELECT ROUND( AVG(votes), 2) AS 'votes', (votes / 50 * 100) FROM `polls`;
```

Will throw up an error message saying that `votes` is a unknown column there.

So is it possible to use the condition (as '**votes**') name for calculating purposes in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

```
COALESCE(ROUND( AVG(p.votes), 2), 0)
```

Second :
no, not possible in the exact same statement. It's possible if the aliased part is in a subquery.
So you have to rewrite

```
(COALESCE(ROUND( AVG(p.votes), 2), 0) / 50 * 100)
```

COALESCE and IFNULL achieve the same goal (maybe not exactly the same way), but COALESCE is ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can not create an alias for field and use the same alias in same select statement.

Use following query:

```
SELECT Ifnull(Round(Avg(votes), 2), 0) AS 'votes', 
       ( Ifnull(Round(Avg(votes), 2), 0) / 50 * 100 ) 
FROM   `polls`;
```